# How to execute view differently if it is coming from a different URL?

Tags: python, django, view

So I want to make a message app in Django. There is a view that used for deleting message. It just hides the message if user clicks delete. It changes the boolean field of message 'hide' to True if executed.

I have two different template, Inbox and Outbox. I want to have delete feature for booth of these. But want to use the same view. I just want to check if the request is comming from Outbox, then I will change to_hide. If the request is comming from Inbox I will change frm_hide. But I don't know how to catch the URL in view and condition them to perform different function.

### Message Model

```py
class Msgs(models.Model):
    to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_user')
    frm = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_user')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    to_hide = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    frm_hide = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.frm} to {self.to}: {self.title}'


## Delete/Hide View

@login_required
def deletemsg(request, msg_id):
    msg = Msgs.objects.get(pk=msg_id)
    msg.frm_hide = True
    msg.save()
    return redirect('/msgs/inbox/')

# inbox url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/msgs/inbox/
# outbox url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/msgs/outbox/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say, your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('msg/<int:msg_id>/<str:msg_type>/', deletemsg, name='inbox-outbox)
]
```

In `views.py`

```
@login_required
def deletemsg(request, msg_id, msg_type):
    msg = Msgs.objects.get(pk=msg_id)
    if msg_type == 'inbox':
        msg.frm_hide = True
        return redirect('your-desired-url')
    if msg_type == 'outbox':
        msg.to_hide = True
        return redirect('your-desired-url')
    # use the following if you redirect to same page for either inbox/outbox. In this case don't use the above two return statement
    # return redirect('your-desired-url')
    raise Http404 # import this before use
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your urls.py you can provide variable object `view_type`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'msgs/(?P<view_type>(inbox|outbox))/$', views.deletemsg),
]
```

and then you can get this param in your view

```py
def deletemsg(request, view_type, msg_id):
    msg = Msgs.objects.get(pk=msg_id)
    # do what you want depends on view_type
    if view_type == 'inbox':
        msg.frm_hide = True
    else:
        msg.to_hide = True

    msg.save()
    return redirect('/msgs/inbox/')
```